# ¿Cómo dar instrucciones de movimiento en el plano usando strings y floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Un robot se mueve en el plano cartesiano empezando del punto (0,0). El robot se puede mover hacia ARRIBA, DERECHA, ABAJO, IZQUIERDA. Suponga que el usuario entró el registro de movimientos del robot así:

```
DIRECCION, DISTANCIA [m]:
ARR 5.1
ABA 3.2
DER 7
IZQ 2.2
DERE 2.3
>>> Error comando "DERE" no reconocido

IZQ 3.2
ABA 8.1
ABA 823ad
>>> Error se esperaba un número; se recibió la expresión no reconocida "823ad".

IZQ 2
*FIN*     (Esto se interpretaría como el fin de las instrucciones de movimiento)
```

Determine la distancia al punto (0,0) y la posición (X,Y) actual del robot.

La parte de determinar la distancia entre la posiicón del robot y el punto (0, 0) es sencillo y se cómo hacerlo, pero no logro concebir la idea de que el programa me entienda ordenes que tengan una cadena (dirección hacia la que moverse) y el número (cuánto se mueve en dicha dirección).

Agradecería alguna pista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola hice un pequeño código que capaz pueda ayudarte, he utilizado una expresión regular para determinar la entrada del usuario la misma puede perfeccionarse aun más.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import re

    movimientos = {
        'arr': 0,
        'aba': 0,
        'izq': 0,
        'der': 0
    }


    def main():
        entrie = None
        while entrie != '*FIN*':
            print('Ingrese el movimiento, *FIN* para terminar\n')
            entrie = input('DIRECCION, DISTANCIA [m]: ')
            matchs = re.match(
                          pattern=r'^(arr|aba|izq|der)\s([0-9])+', 
                          string=entrie, 
                          flags=re.IGNORECASE
                     )
           if entrie != '*FIN*':
               if matchs:
                    movimientos[matchs.group(1)] += int(matchs.group(2))
               else:
                    print('Opción no valida')

        print(movimientos)


     if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

Comment: Si quieres que la distancia acepte decimales deberías usar esta regx: `r'^(arr|aba|izq|der)\s([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'` y cambiar el incremento por `float(matchs.group(2))`.

Comment: Si quieres que la distancia acepte negativos y decimales deberías usar esta regx: `r'^(arr|aba|izq|der)\s((-|\+)?([0-9]+)\.?([0-9])*)$'` y cambiar el incremento por `float(matchs.group(2))`.